# From where http_stub_status_module get details?

Tags: linux, nginx, http

How does the [http_stub_status_module](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_stub_status_module.html) in `nginx` work?

It provides information like below:

```
Active connections: 48 
server accepts handled requests
 26093990 26093990 543636090 
Reading: 0 Writing: 41 Waiting: 7
```

So specifically how does it get `Active connections`, `Reading`, `Writing`, `Waiting` information (`netstat`, `ps`?) ?

Comment: My first instinct would be to read any related doc, then look at the corresponding source code.

Comment: https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/browser/nginx/src/http/modules/ngx_http_stub_status_module.c

Comment: Sorry, I am novice in C/C+ :(